# which register used to pass the JNIEnv for JNI methods in solaris/linux?

Tags: jvm, jit

We know the following calling conversation the this thread,
[What's the calling convention for the Java code in Linux platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693637/whats-the-calling-convention-for-the-java-code-in-linux-platform)
And also it explained that

"You may notice that Java calling convention looks similar to C calling convention but shifted by one argument right. This is done intentionally to avoid extra register shuffling when calling JNI methods (you know, JNI methods have extra JNIEnv* argument prepended to method parameters)."

So does it mean when we called the JNI function such as jclass FindClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name); then JNIEnv value env would be passed to the rdi, and name passed to rsi, however when we called the general non-JNI Java method such as  void printClassName(int Integer1 ,Object obj), then Integer1 is passed to rsi, and obj was passed to the stack as it is not a Integer,it is right?

please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| c_rarg0   c_rarg1  c_rarg2 c_rarg3 c_rarg4 c_rarg5    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| rcx       rdx      r8      r9      rdi*    rsi*       | windows (* not a c_rarg)
| rdi       rsi      rdx     rcx     r8      r9         | solaris/linux
|-------------------------------------------------------|
| j_rarg5   j_rarg0  j_rarg1 j_rarg2 j_rarg3 j_rarg4    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: To study the debug knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given table describes how VM calls *Java* methods.

E.g. when calling Java method `void print(int i, Object o)` it passes

- `this` in `RSI (j_rarg0)`
- `i` in `RDX (j_rarg1)`
- `o` in `RCX (j_rarg2)` - object references are also passed in general purpose registers.

The calling convention is the same, whether a method is declared `native` or not. For a native method there will be a native implementation

```
void Java_ClassName_print(JNIEnv* env, jobject this, jint i, jobject o);
```

This native function follows the standard [platform ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), that is,

- `env` goes to `RDI (c_rarg0)`
- `this` to `RSI (c_rarg1)`
- `i` to `RDX (c_rarg2)`
- `o` to `RCX (c_rarg3)`

Note that due to a wise choice of `j_rargs` vs. `c_rargs`, parameters remained in the same registers.

---

JNI functions like `FindClass` have nothing to do with VM calling convention. They *must* follow the platform ABI. Therefore, the first argument `JNIEnv*` is passed in `RDI` on Linux/x64.

Comment: Much appreciate for your so clearly explanation, you are so kindly. However as you ever mentioned "Up to 6 first integer arguments are passed in registers: rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9, rdi, " in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693637/whats-the-calling-convention-for-the-java-code-in-linux-platform , as the Object o is object reference not the integer , why it also passed in RCX ? The openjdk article also express the same meaning as you saying the the six Integer ...https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CallingSequences, I think I have something misunderstanding.

Comment: @Jacky In the quote above I used "integer" as an opposite to "floating point". An object reference (an address / a pointer / a compressed pointer or whatever) is also a value that fits general purpose (integer) registers.